# Should we answer more than is asked?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes, in a question, the OP asks about a specific problem they face in a larger attempt to do something (this explanation is probably not very clear, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/359323/176889) and [karel](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/359334/176889) for an idea of what I'm talking about).

In such cases, should you answer more than what is asked in the question (even if it is not asked for)?

Should the OP be directed to ask another question if they have more queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to have the person ask multiple questions so that we build a library. And if you can figure out what they're trying to do you can just answer the question and then link to the existing one, which in this case could have been:

- [How to get the native version of Spotify running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running)

I prefer to do it this way because when the Spotify instructions need to get updated we can do it in one place instead of a bunch of places.